# jquery file upload disable thumbnail generation

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am using jQuery File Upload plugin (http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/) for image upload for my website. I am trying to disable `UploadHandler.php` from generating thumbnail image on the server. After some searching, I found this: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/issues/2223

My Code:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');

$options = array (
    'upload_dir' => dirname(__FILE__) . '/uploaddir/',
'image_versions' => array()
);

$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($options);
```

When I try to upload file, it is not generating thumbnail in to the thumbnail folder. But it generate another smaller image on the `uploaddir` folder with the resolution 800 x 800.

So, how to properly disable thumbnail generation in UploadHandler.php?

Thank you.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The default `index.php` file should look like following.

`error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
require('UploadHandler.php');
$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();`

---

In your **`index.php`** file **before** the following function call

`$upload_handler = new UploadHandler();`

add the following code...

```
$options = array(
    // This option will disable creating thumbnail images and will not create that extra folder.
    // However, due to this, the images preview will not be displayed after upload
    'image_versions' => array()
);
```

and then **CHANGE** the `UploadHandler()` function call to the pass the option as follows

`$upload_handler = new UploadHandler($options);`

---

**Short Explanation**

In `UploadHandler.php` file there are default options. One of which is `'image_versions'`. This option sets all relevant options to create server side thumbnail image.

With the above explained changes we are overwriting the `'image_versions'` option to be an empty array (which is same as not having this option).

This disables the server side thumbnail creation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But your example doesn't seems any different than my working code.

Comment: Please check my edit. If your **`index.php`** file **has** the option as I have mentioned above then it should disable the thumbnail creation on server side. If I have misunderstood, can you please clarify what you mean by the _your example doesn't seems any different than my working code._

Comment: Thanks. After I double check, it seems like javascript issue. When the thumbnail is disabled on server side like what you have explained, the website is sending the image twice. Therefore, storing 2 images on the server but with different size.

Comment: Well.. it might be because of some other setting / coding issue. However, I believe your question can be / should have solved with the above answer.

Answer (score -1):

uncomment these lines in UploadHandler.php around line 103...

```
       /*'thumbnail' => array(
               // Uncomment the following to force the max
                // dimensions and e.g. create square thumbnails:
                //'crop' => true,
                'max_width' => 80,
                'max_height' => 80
            ) */
```

Comment: Use the options array. If you make your changes direct in UploadHandler, you have to change it on each update.